# Feature temporally free in iphone app

Tags: ios4, in-app-purchase

It's possible to have a free feature in my iphone game and then charge people for it after some time trough an in app-purchase?.

Also, It's possible to change the price of an in-app purchase after it goes life ? ( for example, make an in-app purchase free and then change its price weeks ater the purchase went live).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [THIS](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009):

> In-App Purchase can be offered in both
>   free and paid apps—no free In-App
>   Purchases are available.

You cannot set your in-app purchase FREE and then change it to paid, beacuse you cannot set an in-app purchase price less than $0.99..